# How can I insert keyframes and start an animation on a newly rigged model? (2.78)

Tags: animation, keyframes

within my blend I have use Rigify to rig my model. How can I start the animation process and insert keyframes. If i'm correct, I have set up the action editor correctly, I just cant seem to be able to insert keyframes. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Select a bone in the 3D view, make sure you're in "Pose" Mode of the 3D view, then press "i" and select the properties which you want to keyframe.